Number 201.000.000 in German?
How to say the number 201 000 000 in German? I've asked several speakers and they've given different answers. If I remember correctly, "zweihundertein Millionen", "zweihunderteins Millionen", "zweihundertundein Millionen" have all been suggested by people who have more or less expertise in German. (All were fully proficient, but to my knowledge none were monolingual German native speakers).
Which is correct?

a monolingual German speaker will not be able to understand your question for his lack to understand English ;)

Yeah, well, by "monolingual" I meant someone with only one native language, not someone who speaks only one language. So someone who in childhood spoke only German at home and went to a German-speaking school would count as "monolingual" even if they were taught other languages at school.

@hilssu: Ahm ... No. Quote from Cambridge English dictionary (bold marks added by me): »monolingual: able to use one language well.« You have to be able to use English well to understand your question, and you have be able to use German well to answer it. This gives two languages you need to be able to use well, what contradicts the definition of monolingual.

All of them. This is because there's both the number eins and the article ein which mean both one. The number eins isn't declined but the article is. And if you use the number to quantify a noun it must be declined as a whole as well. And you can leave out the und before ein.

zweihundert(und)eine Million
zweihundert(und)eins Millionen
zweihundert(und)ein Millionen Dinge
zweihundert(und)eins Millionen Dinge


zweihundereinS Millionen klingt für mich falsch. Wenn das Wort nicht mit einem Nomen zusammen gebraucht wird, is es korrekt: Das Ergebnis der Rechnung ist zweihunderteins Millionen. Aber: Du schuldest mir noch zweihundertein Millionen Euro.
